# Captcha With no model and no ActiveForm

Tags: php, yii

How can i use the  **CCaptcha** not using models (rules) and ActiveForms?

Just create and check. e.g. through AJAX

Comment: For example i have a modal window which has captcha field, so all data transefrting trought simple AJAX...

Comment: Can we see the code you are working on? If you can talk us through it, we may be able to help.

Comment: I have a modal windows with fields "Username" And "text". Ajax handler getting XMLHttpRequest Data. Need add CAPTCHA on form.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Yii models for forms even if you're making modal ajax forms.

You simply need to bind the onsubmit method to make ajax call with the form data instead of reloading the whole page.

I can show you this example of Ajax form on this page:
http://www.eldeposit.com/agencia/1552/oi-real-estate

Uses Yii and has captcha.

In this case it is not a modal but it is a Ajax form with captcha.

```
jQuery('#contactar_submit_btn').click(function(){
    var submit_label = jQuery('#contactar_submit_btn').attr('value');
    jQuery('#contactar').ajaxSubmit(
      {'dataType': 'json', 'success': function(data) {
        jQuery('#contactar_submit_btn').attr('disabled', false);
        jQuery('#contactar_submit_btn').attr('value', submit_label);
        var timestamp = Number(new Date());
        var csrc = jQuery('#contactarCCaptcha').attr('src');
        jQuery('.captcha_image').attr('src',csrc+'?t='+timestamp);
        if (data.error.length > 0)
          alert(data.error);
        else {
          jQuery('#contactar_target').html(data.success);
          jQuery('#contactar').resetForm();
          jQuery('#contactar_target').show();
        }
      },
      'beforeSubmit': function() {
        jQuery('#contactar_target').hide();
        jQuery('#contactar_submit_btn').attr('value','enviando..');
        jQuery('#contactar_submit_btn').attr('disabled', true);
      }});
  });
```

The "trick" in making the captcha work properly is to make a refresh on the image with a random parameter in the original url. This is required because if we keep the same image but send the ajax request, the captcha will not match if user clicks submit multiple times.

Another way around would that I often use is to:
1. Create full Yii form inside a controller that I load by ajax and show in a modal with a ID
2. When clicking submit, you make ajax call to the same controller and totally replace modal ID content with ajax response

Hope it helps you someway!